# Select multiple fields from columns with distinct and limit

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my original code and i get only results for the title.

```
$result = $db->fetchRowList("select Distinct `title` from ".TABLE_ADS." where `title` like '$term%' limit 10");
```

I want get results and from another columns and fields like

```
$result = $db->fetchRowList("select Distinct `title` from ".TABLE_ADS." where `title` like '$term%' and ".TABLE_MESSANGES." where `messange` like '$term%'  and ".TABLE_CARS." where `model` like '$term%' limit 10");
```

Comment: You are attempting to search for your term in 3 different tables. `TBL_ADS, TBL_MESSANGES, TABLE_CARS` -- are these three related in any way, or are you just trying to combine 3 operations in one query?

Comment: I Don't now how can do that can you please show me an example?

Comment: Please edit your question above to include the structures of the 3 tables you're trying to work with

Comment: I Don't now how to, see my original select the other is the table with the names i want to show like title from TABLE_ADS, messange from TABLE_MESSANGES, and model from TABLE_CARS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to select a single column from 3 different tables at the same time. If that is the case, you want to use a [Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

```
"(SELECT `title` FROM ".TABLE_ADS." WHERE `title` LIKE '$term%') UNION (SELECT `messange` FROM ".TABLE_MESSANGES." WHERE `messange` LIKE '$term%') UNION (SELECT `model` FROM ".TABLE_CARS." WHERE `model` LIKE '$term%') LIMIT 10"
```

It's important to note, you won't be able to tell which rows came from which tables. You'll need to add a controlling column to identify, like so:

```
"(SELECT `title`, 'ad' as `table` FROM ".TABLE_ADS." WHERE `title` LIKE '$term%') UNION (SELECT `messange`, 'messange' as `table` FROM ".TABLE_MESSANGES." WHERE `messange` LIKE '$term%') UNION (SELECT `model`, 'car' as `table` FROM ".TABLE_CARS." WHERE `model` LIKE '$term%') LIMIT 10"
```

Comment: It's a quick way to determine which table the row came from. All of your rows will have a column called 'table', if the row came from the TABLE_ADS table, that column will be 'ad', if it came from TABLE_MESSANGES, that column will be 'messange', and if it came from TABLE_CARS, that column will be 'car'.

Comment: With your answer is not working but is working with this.. $result = $db->fetchRowList("SELECT `word` from ".mauto_complete_searches." where `word` like '$term%' UNION SELECT `title` from ".TABLE_ADS." where `title` like '$term%' UNION SELECT `elements` from ".FIELDS_LANG." where `elements` like '$term%' limit 10"); What is wrong in your anwer?

Comment: That's the same as my first answer. If that is sufficient for your needs, you don't have to use the second option I gave you. If you want me to figure out why the second one doesn't work, you're going to need to give me an actual error message.